# plot two different datasets in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to upload two different datasets and then generate a plot together, one of them in the geom_line() and the other in the geom_point(). I have created two different fileInput in the UI to upload the datasets. However, I'm totally lost and the code won't execute. What can be the solution here to perform this?

```
ui <- navbarPage("pp",
                 tabPanel("Vis",
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              fileInput("upload1","Observed Data",
                                        accept=c('text/csv', 
                                                 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                                 '.csv')
                                        
                              ),
                              selectInput('xcol1', 'X Variable', "",width=140),
                              selectInput('ycol1', 'Y Variable', "", selected = "",width=140),
                              
                              fileInput("upload2","Simulated Data",
                                        accept=c('text/csv', 
                                                 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                                 '.csv')
                                        
                              ),
                              selectInput('xcol2', 'X Variable', "",width=140),
                              selectInput('ycol2', 'Y Variable', "", selected = "",width=140)
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                              plotOutput("plot")


                            )
                          )
                          
                          
                          
                          
                 )
                 
                 )
```

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$upload1) 
    
    inFile <- input$upload1
    

    df_1 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
                   

  updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol1', label ='X vairable',
                    choices = names(df_1), selected = names(df_1)[1])

  updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol1', label ='Y vairable',
                    choices = names(df_1), selected = names(df_1)[2])

  return(df_1)
  })

#####

 data_2 <- reactive({ 
    req(input$upload2) 
    
    inFile <- input$upload2
    
    
    df_2 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol2', label ='X vairable',
                      choices = names(df_2), selected = names(df_2)[3])

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol2', label ='Y vairable',
                      choices = names(df_2), selected = names(df_2)[4])
  
    return(df_2)
  })


 output$plot <-renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data(), aes(.data[[input$xcol1]], .data[[input$ycol1]] *1000, size=1) +
      geom_line(data_2(),  aes(.data_2[[input$xcol2]]/60, .data_2[[input$ycol2]], size=1) +
      theme_bw()


  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your plotting code. First. The first argument of each `geom` is the `mapping`. If you pass a dataset you have to explicitly name the argument, i.e. do e.g. `data = data()`. Second, there is no `.data_2` pronoun. Simply use `.data`. Finally: Keep an eye on where you set parentheses. (;

Note: I uncommented all code related to the file input and simply used `mtcars` for both datasets.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "pp",
  tabPanel(
    "Vis",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        # fileInput("upload1", "Observed Data",
        #   accept = c(
        #     "text/csv",
        #     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        #     ".csv"
        #   )
        # ),
        selectInput("xcol1", "X Variable", "", width = 140),
        selectInput("ycol1", "Y Variable", "", selected = "", width = 140),
        # fileInput("upload2", "Simulated Data",
        #   accept = c(
        #     "text/csv",
        #     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        #     ".csv"
        #   )
        # ),
        selectInput("xcol2", "X Variable", "", width = 140),
        selectInput("ycol2", "Y Variable", "", selected = "", width = 140)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    # req(input$upload1)

    # inFile <- input$upload1

    df_1 <- mtcars # read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

    updateSelectInput(session,
      inputId = "xcol1", label = "X vairable",
      choices = names(df_1), selected = names(df_1)[1]
    )

    updateSelectInput(session,
      inputId = "ycol1", label = "Y vairable",
      choices = names(df_1), selected = names(df_1)[2]
    )

    return(df_1)
  })

  #####

  data_2 <- reactive({
    # req(input$upload2)

    # inFile <- input$upload2

    df_2 <- mtcars # read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

    updateSelectInput(session,
      inputId = "xcol2", label = "X vairable",
      choices = names(df_2), selected = names(df_2)[3]
    )

    updateSelectInput(session,
      inputId = "ycol2", label = "Y vairable",
      choices = names(df_2), selected = names(df_2)[4]
    )

    return(df_2)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = data(), aes(.data[[input$xcol1]], .data[[input$ycol1]] * 1000), size = 1) +
      geom_line(data = data_2(), aes(.data[[input$xcol2]] / 60, .data[[input$ycol2]]), size = 1) +
      theme_bw()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5810
#> Warning: Error in is_string: argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

[image]